# repeat a Mouse Over event

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Hi I have an actionscript that moves a box across the stage when the mouse is over a left or right arrow shaped button . The script below does just that. BUT what I want to do is have the box repeatedly move until the mouse is moved off the arrow button . I have tried all ways can anybody please point me in the right direction .I have removed a lot of the code but hope this is enough to get my point across.  Thanks Mick

```
right_arrow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.mouseOver, moveR) ;
left_arrow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.mouseOver, moveL) ;

function moveL(e:MouseEvent)    {
box_image.x = box_image.x - 5 ;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use the [setInterval](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/utils/package.html#setInterval%28%29) Method:

```
right_arrow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.mouseOver, handleMouseOver) ;
right_arrow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.mouseOut, handleMouseOut) ;

function handleMouseOver( event:MouseEvent):void {
  setTimeout( moveBoxR, 500 ); //every 500ms
}

function handleMouseOut( event:MouseEvent):void {
  clearTimeout( moveBoxR );
}

function moveBoxR() {
  box_image.x -= 5 ;
}
```

or the [ENTER_FRAME Event](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/events/Event.html#ENTER_FRAME)

```
right_arrow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.mouseOver, handleMouseOver) ;
right_arrow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.mouseOut, handleMouseOut) ;

function handleMouseOver( event:MouseEvent):void {
  addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBoxR )
}

function handleMouseOut( event:MouseEvent):void {
  removeEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBoxR )
}

function moveBoxR(event:Event) {
  box_image.x -= 5 ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, don't know how smooth it will be though:

- set a flag to indicate the mouse over
- implement an on frame handler which checks the flag and if set moves the box
- on mouse out, reset the flag